# How to create a neat table from ugly rows of data?

Tags: python, data-manipulation

For example, I imported a dataset from excel looks like this with just one column and many rows, with repeated information such as name, phone and title:

table 
---------
0  name1
1  phone1
2  title1
3  name2
4  phone2
5  title2
6  name3
7  phone3
8  title3

And I want to build a table from this with 3 columns name, phone, title
and extract that information into this new table. such as:

name phone title 
name1 phone1 title1 
name2 phone2 title2

and such... How should I approach this problem? I'm using Python with Jupyter Notebook.

++ So here, all name/phone/title are different words, for example, names can be Sarah Kim, Andrew m. white, Mike yesman. Phone can be 111-222-3333, 333-444-5555, and so on. And I have more than 500+ rows, so my first try is trying to use REGEX to separate name, phone, and title. I am using pandas dataframe, and I wanted to learn how to approach problems like this, rather than just getting the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? And what was your result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: @G.Anderson I don't even have many ideas of how to approach a problem like this. I'm not asking for code answers but more like how to think through and what (?) to consider.

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: If you want lined-up columns, then it follows that all the values in a given column need to be the same width. Use Python formatting to make each value in a column take up the same number of characters, padded with spaces where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to create a basic table. Define each of your variables, in this case by using an array of strings. Then use pd.DataFrame to title each column and then assign the values.

```
import pandas as pd

names = ('name1', 'name2')
phones = ('phone1', 'phone2')
titles = ('title1', 'title2')

example = pd.DataFrame({
    "Names": names,
    "Phones": phones,
    "Titles": titles,
})
example
```

Output:

```
    Names   Phones  Titles
0   name1   phone1  title1
1   name2   phone2  title2
```

Comment: However, I will have actual names, phone numbers, and titles in the table rather than simplified version of name1, name2. And also the number of rows is over 500.... Will there be a better way? I'm thinking using Regex, but not sure if that's smart way

Comment: He said that he imported that from Excel, so your answer has nothing to do with his question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using pandas *(although pandas will likely be faster/more efficient)*:

```
data = ['name1', 'phone1', 'title1', 'name2', 'phone2', 'title2']

print("Name Phone Title")
for name, phone, title in zip(*[iter(data)]*3):
  print(name, phone, title)
```

---

Result

```
Name Phone Title
name1 phone1 title1
name2 phone2 title2
```